# Plotting seasonal time series in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I was wondering if anyone knows how to better plot time-series data where the x-axis on the ggplot object will be a factor or a character classed object. Below is an example of a population, where diversity lowers in the winter and goes extinct. The population then will increase in the fall. Is there a better way to present this data? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

d <- rep(c(0, 10, 6, 0), 4)
time <- rep(c("Fall", "Fall", "Winter", "Winter"), 4)
year <- rep(1:4, each=4)
dt <- data.table(cbind(d, time, year))
dt$d <- as.numeric(dt$d)
dt$year <- as.numeric(dt$year)

ggplot(dt, aes(x=interaction(time, year), y=d, group=1)) +
  geom_line(position="identity", size=1) +
  geom_point(size=2)+
  labs(x="Year",
       y= "Diversity") +
  theme_classic()
```

Specifically, I would like a break between every Winter and Fall. So a gap between every new year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use different approach - use colour to visualise break between every Winter and Fall (`geom_rect`), transform x-axis to continuous (from `1` to size of the data).

Using OPs data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# Prepare data
# Create continuous data for the x-axis
dt[, X := 1:.N]
# Define begging of the year
break_labels <- dt[, min(X), year]

# Plot
ggplot(dt, aes(X, d)) +
  # Use 0.5 to extend colour around the X
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = X - 0.5, xmax = X + 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = time)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(size = 1, linetype = 2) +
  # Specify wanted colour code
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#EDBB99", "#D6EAF8")) +
  # Specify breaks only for the begging of the year
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = break_labels$V1, labels = break_labels$year) +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Diversity",
    fill = "Season"
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to show how to use two different y variables. Note that in this solution the zero datapoints are directly below the the measured data points. From what I understand you are trying to accomplish you will need different time points for the periods with measured values and the periods with extinction.

An easy way to create a break in the lines is to replace the zeros with NA. Depending on your use, you will likely want to extend the y-axis to go to zero. I prefer using `coord_cartesian` for this. In the second graph we alter the y aesthetic to use the full d column and thus get the zero points to show.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

d <- rep(c(0, 10, 6, 0), 4)
time <- rep(c("Fall", "Fall", "Winter", "Winter"), 4)
year <- rep(1:4, each=4)
dt <- data.table(cbind(d, time, year))
dt$d <- as.numeric(dt$d)
dt$year <- as.numeric(dt$year)


# Plot with breaks in line, replace 0 with NA
dt <- dplyr::mutate(dt, d_na = ifelse(d == 0, NA, d))

ggplot(dt, aes(x=interaction(time, year), y=d_na, group=1)) +
  geom_line(position="identity", size=1) +
  geom_point(size=2)+
  labs(x="Year",
       y= "Diversity") +
  theme_classic() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,max(dt$d, na.rm = T)))

# Plot with zero points, use two different y variables
ggplot(dt, aes(x=interaction(time, year), y=d_na, group=1)) +
  geom_line(position="identity", size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = d), size=2)+
  labs(x="Year",
       y= "Diversity") +
  theme_classic() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,max(dt$d, na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: Would there be a way to have the 0 plotted as a point and still make a break between every winter and fall?